# Add domain string to validation messages in CakePHP models

Tags: validation, cakephp, localization, model, internationalization

Is it possible to add a domain string to validation messages in CakePHP models? I have all my messages localized with `__d()`:

```
echo __d('my_app_name', 'This is a regular message');
```

But validation messages in a model are plain strings or `sprintf` arguments:

```
'my_field' => array(
  'my_rule' => array(
    'rule' => 'alphanumeric',
    'message' => 'Only letters and numbers allowed',
  )
)

'another_field' => array(
  'another_rule' => array(
    'rule' => 'alphanumeric',
    'message' => ('Only %s and %s allowed', 'letters', 'numbers'),
  )
)
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using CakePHP 2.x:

Cake's `Model` class has a Property `validationDomain`, you might just add

`public $validationDomain = "yourdomain";`

to your model to get what you want.

Info from API:

> ValidationDomain (string)
>
> > Name of the validation string domain to use when translating validation errors.

See http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered changing the validationDomain property of the [model](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model)? (Edited: I just noticed that @Nappo has suggested this)

Or if that's not flexible enough for you, you could override CakePhp's `invalidate()` function in your Model like so:

```
/**
 * Overrides Model.php's invalidate function
 */
public function invalidate($field, $value = true) {
  if (is_string($value)) {
    return parent::invalidate($field, __d('my_app_name', $value));
  }
  else {
    return parent::invalidate($field);
  }
}
```

You could put this in your AppModel or in the specific model you wish to change the message for.

Comment: Have missed the `validationDomain` attribute :( It works for me. Thanks anyway